# failed to run phonegap 3.0 cli android app (No such file or directory)

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I am trying to build my first phonegap app using version 3.0

I followed theses steps:

1. I installed NodeJS successfully on my mac os
2. on the shell --> $ sudo npm install -g phonegap
3. then I tried build the app but I got this exception

Here is the code sample

```
$ phonegap create my-app  
$ cd my-app 
$ phonegap run android
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
[error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project. /bin/sh: /Users/mac/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.0.0/bin/create: No such file or directory
```

I found that the directory /Users/mac/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.0.0 is empty

Phonegap version is

```
phonegap --version
3.0.0-0.14.0
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Same here but for iOS

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem. I fixed it by downloading the missing files (the whole of the bin directory) as a zip from the [cordova-android](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android) project on github and extracting them to the empty /Users/mac/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.0.0 directory.

I also found I had to run it the command as sudo.

Comment: Could you be specific about which files you extracted?
There are no logs indicating that any reqs are missing...

Comment: @Big-OClaire updated answer. It was the whole bin directory. The files aren't dependencies as such, just missing from the cordova installation some reason.